# Why this JavaScript is not working in Mozilla FF?

Tags: javascript, mozilla

Its a struts 1.2 application.
I have a java script function.
Its working in IE and Chrome but not in Mozilla.
It is supposed to change the button after clicking that button and perform some action.

```
function changeButton(obj)
{
obj.form.action=obj.form.action + "&submitType=Bucket  Usage";   
obj.form.submit();
document.getElementById("submit_btn").innerHTML="<img src=x.jpg>";window.status="Form Submitted, Please wait...";return true;
}
```

And the call is from

onclick="javascript:changeButton(this);"

Please help.

Comment: Modifying `window.status` works only in IE6 and older, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Does it work in other browsers? Have you tried debugging with Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure `obj.form` is actually the form object you want?

I'm betting the spaces aren't going over well in the action attribute.

what type of element is `submit_btn`?

the `javascript:` part should not be present in the `onclick` value.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `javascript:` from the onclick attribute.

`obj.form.submit()` will make the browser go to the URL specified in the form elements action attribute, and any JavaScript after that line will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other people said:

```
function changeButton(obj)
{
    obj.form.action += "&submitType=Bucket%20%20Usage";     
    document.getElementById("submit_btn").innerHTML="<img src='x.jpg' />";
    window.status="Form Submitted, Please wait...";
    obj.form.submit(); //if the button clicked is a submit button, this is probably not neccessary
}
```

`onclick="changeButton(this);"`